# OutOfMemory while adding pictures to Excel Sheet

Tags: c#, .net, excel, image

I have problem with memory.

I want do add pictures to my excel. Picuters are on azure blob.

After 1k of added pictures my program slowing so much till outofmemory exception.

I will paste my code here:

```
string filePath = @"excel.xlsx";
    int i = 0;
    public void Generate(int worksheetnumber)
    {
        using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            var package = new ExcelPackage(fileStream);
            ExcelWorksheet workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[worksheetnumber];
            workSheet.Column(2).Width = 21;
            workSheet.Column(4).Width = 21;

            for (int j = workSheet.Dimension.Start.Row + 1; j <= workSheet.Dimension.End.Row; j++)
            {
                InsertImage(workSheet, j, 1);
                InsertImage(workSheet, j, 3);
            }

            string path = string.Format(@"{0}.xlsx", worksheetnumber);
            Stream stream2 = File.Create(path);
            package.SaveAs(stream2);
            stream2.Close();
        }
    }

    private void InsertImage(ExcelWorksheet workSheet, int j, int columnNumber)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(workSheet.Cells[j, columnNumber].Text))
        {
            try
            {
                var splittedUrlHash = workSheet.Cells[j, columnNumber].Text.Split('/');
                using (var stream = DownloadBlobFileToStream(splittedUrlHash[1], splittedUrlHash[0], SHOP))
                {
                    Image image = Image.FromStream(stream);
                    var picture = workSheet.Drawings.AddPicture(string.Format("{0}{1}", j, columnNumber+1), image);
                    stream.Close();
                    picture.From.Column = columnNumber;
                    picture.From.Row = j - 1;
                    picture.To.Column = columnNumber;
                    picture.To.Row = j - 1;
                    picture.SetSize(150, 120);

                    workSheet.Row(j).Height = 100;
                    Debug.WriteLine("Dodano obrazek - {0}", i);
                    i++;
                }
            }
            catch (System.ArgumentException e)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

I want to admit, I have a link images in Columns 1 and 3. Images are locating in cols 2 and 4.

Is there any solution to handle this error in this case without losing images, or leaving empty cells

Comment: When the exception is thrown, have you checked which objects are currently in memory?

Comment: Yeah, excel sheet -> Memory Stream